# C++ segmentation fault when trying to resolve a CORBA reference

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, corba, ace, tao

When im trying to resolve a CORBA reference I receive a segmentation fault. Either im blind or I have done something really stupid for this not work. Im using ACE 5.7.9 TAO 1.7.9 for CORBA. Wondering if anyone can help me please ???

The segmentation fault seems to be happening on the line "serverRef = Corba::Orb::getOrb().resolveObjectReference  (myIOR.c_str());" as commenting this line will cause the application to run fine.

I have copied all the dependan code below.

```
bool ClsSend::ServerObject::resolveServerRef()
{
  clssendlog << debug << "In ClsSend::ServerObject::resolveServerRef 1" << endl;
 bool referenceIsUsable = true;
 ostringstream errMsg;

 // Are we dealing with a new reference?
 if (CORBA::is_nil (serverRef.in()))
 {
   try {
     Monitor crit (mutexCoreRef);

     if (CORBA::is_nil (serverRef.in()))
     {
       // Step 1: Resolve the object reference
       serverRef = Corba::Orb::getOrb().resolveObjectReference <GenericServerWithTransport> (myIOR.c_str());

       // Step 2: Ping to check connectivity if reference is not null
       if (!CORBA::is_nil (serverRef.in()))
         serverRef->ping();
       else
       {
         errMsg << "Not registered in naming server.";
         referenceIsUsable = false;
       }
     }
   } catch (const CORBA::COMM_FAILURE &exc) {
     errMsg << "CORBA::COMM_FAILURE";
     referenceIsUsable = false;
     setRefNil();
   } catch (const NamingException &exc) {
     errMsg << exc;
     referenceIsUsable = false;
     setRefNil();
   } catch (...) {
     errMsg << "Unknown exception";
     referenceIsUsable = false;
     setRefNil();
   }
 }
 return referenceIsUsable;
```

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

resolveObjectReference outline,

```
// Resolve a reference to an object, return a nil object reference if none is bound
// Specify the name with a delimited string
template<class T> typename T::_var_type resolveObjectReference(const string &name,
    char delimiter = '/')
{
  return Corba::resolveObjectReference<T> (orb_.in(), name, delimiter);
}

// Resolve a reference to an object, return a nil object reference if none is bound
// Specify the name with a delimited c-style string
template<class T>
typename T::_var_type resolveObjectReference(const CORBA::ORB_ptr & orb, const string &name, char delimiter = '/')
{
  return resolveObjectReference<T> (orb, convertToCosName(name, delimiter));
}

// Resolve a reference to an object, return a nil object reference if none is bound
// Specify the name with a CosNaming::Name object
template<class T>
typename T::_var_type resolveObjectReference(const CORBA::ORB_ptr & orb, const CosNaming::Name &name)
{
  typename T::_var_type typedObj;
  CORBA::Object_var obj;

  // Check it is a valid name
  assert_throw(name.length() > 0);

  // Try to resolve the object reference
  try
  {
    obj = getNamingContext(orb)->resolve(name);

    // If the object reference was bound to nil emit a warning but return nil, do not throw
    if (CORBA::is_nil(obj.in()))
    {
      liblog << warning << "Object reference " << toString(name)
          << " bound to nil in naming service" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
      typedObj = T::_narrow(obj.in());

      // If the object reference narrowed to nil this indicates the object was of the wrong type
      if (CORBA::is_nil(typedObj.in()))
      {
        liblog << error << "Object reference " << toString(name)
            << " is not of the expected type " << typeid(T).name() << endl;
        throw NamingException("Object reference narrows to a nil");
      }
    }
  }
  catch (const CosNaming::NamingContext::NotFound &exc)
  {
    // Object not bound - return nil
  }
  return typedObj;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Local function - getNamingContext
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CosNaming::NamingContext_var getNamingContext(CORBA::ORB_ptr orb)
{
  // Get the initial reference to the naming service
  CORBA::Object_var nameService;

  // Try to get a reference to the naming service
  nameService = orb->resolve_initial_references("NameService");
  if (CORBA::is_nil(nameService.in()))
  {
    liblog << error << "Name service reference bound to nil" << endl;
    throw NamingException("Naming service reference bound to nil");
  }

  // cerr << "Name service IOR: " << getORB()->object_to_string (nameService) << endl;

  // Narrow the reference to the root naming context
  CosNaming::NamingContext_var rootContext =
      CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(nameService.in());
  if (CORBA::is_nil(rootContext.in()))
  {
    liblog << error << "Name service reference resolved to nil" << endl;
    throw NamingException("Naming service reference resolves to nil");
  }
  return rootContext;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Local function - convertToCosName
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CosNaming::Name convertToCosName(const string &strname, char delimiter)
{
  const char *name = strname.c_str();

  CosNaming::Name cosName;
  cosName.length(count(name, name + strlen(name), delimiter) + 1);

  size_t index = 0;
  const char *next = strchr(name, delimiter);
  if (next == NULL)
  {
    next = name + strlen(name);
  }
  while (next != NULL)
  {
    cosName[index].id = string(name, next).c_str();
    cosName[index++].kind = CORBA::string_dup("");
    if (*next)
    {
      name = next + 1;
      next = strchr(name, delimiter);
      if (next == NULL)
      {
        next = name + strlen(name);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      next = NULL;
    }
  }
  return cosName;
}
```

Comment: It is kind of a bad question if you don't provide a core dump. People can only guess.

Comment: unfortunately it didnt produce a core dump. i was able to get a stack trace from gdb but even then it pointed something towards Dynamic Request which my guess was a false error. This is a threaded application hence it probably didnt show it at the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dang, that's a lot of code in a question...

My next look in a case like this would be to split that offending line:

`serverRef = Corba::Orb::getOrb().resolveObjectReference (myIOR.c_str());`

Into as many parts as possible, and try to see which part is crashing. After that, try to see what is wrong with that one part.